# pass xml and get strongly typed .NET OBjects

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xsd2code

I've been using Linq To XML in order to mapp the XML DOcument to .NET OBjects.

Could anyone please guide me whether there any too exist where I can pass XML Document (string) and it returns strongly Type .NET OBject?

I've been looking at XSD2Code and having a problem passing the whole XML as it seems to create separate classes for each Elements.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty easy:

1. take your XML and run it through the `xsd.exe` command line tool:

   ```
   c:\> xsd.exe yourfile.xml
   ```

   This will produce a corresponding XML schema file (`yourfile.xsd`)
2. Run the `xsd.exe` tool again, this time on the XSD file, to get a C# class:

   ```
   c:\> xsd.exe /c yourfile.xsd
   ```

   This will produce a C# class in `yourfile.cs` which represents your XML content
3. Using that class in a project, just deserialize your XML into a C# object:

   ```
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourClass));

   var result = ser.Deserialize(new FileStream(@"D:\temp\yourfile.xml", FileMode.Open));
   ```

   If everything worked as it should, your `result` now contains a C# class instance that represents 1:1 that XML file's content.

That's it!

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, What I'm after is how to deserialize the XML Document and get strongly typed .NET Object.

Comment: @Myagdi I guess you mean type safety. Unfortunately we don't have an `XmlSerializer<T>` that returns T on `Deserialize()` so you have to cast from `object` to `T` yourself. I still wonder why they didn't introduced that with generics in .net2.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `xsd` util.

IIRC, you call it `xsd /c yourschema.xsd > classes.cs`.

If you have a bunch of XML without schema, you can also use `xsd` to try infer a schema. That should be a good starting point anyways :)